# Some images doesn't appear using Universal Image Loader and a slow internet connection

Tags: android, image, performance, connection

In the layout I've a Gallery with 10 images and a ListView with 10 more images.

If the internet connection is not good, the images inside the Gallery are never loaded and the images inside the ListView, after several scrolls up and down, become to appear randomly. But if I try to open the same images with a better internet connection (with a Wi-Fi connection), all of them get loaded.

All the images has the same size (206 × 131) and similar weight (about 13 KB). The server from which the images get loaded is hosted on Amazon.

Can any one help me?

1. UIL version = 1.9.1
2. Android version tested on = 4.1.2
3. Configuration =

   `File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(getApplicationContext(), "SomeApp/Cache");
   ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new  ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
     .threadPoolSize(3)
     .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
     .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
     .discCache(new FileCountLimitedDiscCache(cacheDir, 100))
     .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(getApplicationContext()))
     .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
     .writeDebugLogs().build();
   ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
   ImageLoader.getInstance().handleSlowNetwork(true);`
4. Display options =

   `DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
     .cacheOnDisc(true)
     .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
     .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
     .build();
   ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(item.getImageUrl(), imageNews,options);`
5. XML layout =

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >
       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="@dimen/img_news_width"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/img_news_height"
           android:layout_marginLeft="2dp" >
           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/imageNews"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
               android:src="@drawable/default_img"
               android:scaleType="fitXY" />
       </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>`